# DataTable 1.10.15 table is displaying all results rather than displaying 10 rows in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am using CodeIgniter 3 to set up an application. The application has a logs page that is supposed to display the ten most recent records on the screen from the desired MySQL table. The data is received as a JSON object. The DataTable should then allow the user to paginate to the other records accordingly. The issue is that all of the returned records are displayed even if there are more than ten of them.

Here are my CDN links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
var Table = {
/**
 *
 * @function init
 * @description Initializes the table object
 * @memberOf Table
 * @param {string} name Name used as dom element id
 * @param {string} url Url to data source
 * @param {array} columns Column names
 * @returns void
 */
init: function(name,url,columns) {
    this.col_array = columns;
    this.name = name;
    this.url = url;
    this.createTable();

    $('table#'+this.name).DataTable( {
            serverSide: true,
            displayStart: 10,
            sDom: '<"top"lp>t<"bottom"i><"clear">',
            ajax: url,
            columns: this.getColumns()
    });

    var dTable = $('table#'+this.name).DataTable();
    for(var i in this.col_array){
        $(dTable.column(i).header()).text(this.col_array[i]);
    }

},
/**
 * @function createTable
 * @description Creates a dom element for the table object
 * @memberOf Table
 * @returns void
 */
createTable: function() {
    $("div#table ").append('<table id="'+this.name+'" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" />');
},
/**
 * @function getColumns
 * @description Return an array of column data
 * @memberOf Table
 * @returns {Array|Table.getColumns.c}
 */
getColumns: function(){
    var c = [];

    for(var k in this.col_array){
        c.push({ "data": this.col_array[k]});
    }

    return c;
},
};
```

Here is my HTML markup for the table:

```
<div id="table" style="width:95%; margin-left:10px;"></div>
```

Here is how I am calling the Table in my js file:

```
Table.init('logs', location + '/get_data', ['Username', 'Date', 'Login', 'Logout']);
```

Comment: When serverSide is set to true, it is up the to server, not the client, to send back just ten rows.  If you are in fact sending all the results back, remove serverSide or set it to false, then the DataTables on the client will take care of it.

Comment: Thank you. Turning serverSide off worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually see a number of issues with your code.  Look at my inline comments.
Also, you are not really maintaining state (from what I see above) so I would use regular functions instead of creating an object.

```
    var Table = {
        /**
         *
         * @function init
         * @description Initializes the table object
         * @memberOf Table
         * @param {string} name Name used as dom element id
         * @param {string} url Url to data source
         * @param {array} columns Column names
         * @returns void
         */
        init: function (name, url, columns) {
            this.col_array = columns;
            this.name = name;
            this.url = url;
            this.createTable();
            // ***************************** I added the datatable to your object instead of a variable
            this.dTable = $('table#' + this.name).DataTable({
                // **************************** this shouild be false if you are sending all of the data 
                // ************ back from the server
                serverSide: false,
                // ****************************** This attribute causes to start displaying data
                // at row ten, is that what you intended?  otherwise, used length if you are setting rows per page
                displayStart: 10,
                // rows per page
                pageLength:10,
                // sDom is legacy, just use "dom"
                "dom": '<"top"lp>t<"bottom"i><"clear">',
                ajax: url,
                columns: this.getColumns()
            });

            //    var dTable = $('table#' + this.name).DataTable();

            //  ************** this problem will not work. See note below in getColumns section
           // for (var i in this.col_array) {
           //     $(dTable.column(i).header()).text(this.col_array[i]);
          //  }

        },
        /**
         * @function createTable
         * @description Creates a dom element for the table object
         * @memberOf Table
         * @returns void
         */
        createTable: function () {
            // ***************** you need to add the thead tag for dynamic columns
            $("div#table ").append('<table id="' + this.name + '" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" ><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');
        },
        /**
         * @function getColumns
         * @description Return an array of column data
         * @memberOf Table
         * @returns {Array|Table.getColumns.c}
         */
        getColumns: function () {
            var c = [];

            for (var k in this.col_array) {

                // ***************************** when using dynamic columns (columns not a part of your html)
                // ***************** you need to add  the title attribute
                c.push({ "data": this.col_array[k], "title": this.col_array[k] });
            }

            return c;
        },
    };
```

Comment: I will look into your suggestion. The code looks good. Thank you for the input.